# echoing into php brackets

Tags: php, email, echo

I am trying to create a mail form, but i want the mail to be sent to different people based on the email address they gave when they registered.

How can i replace example@live.co.uk with `<?php echo $row_DetailRS1['email']; ?>`

```
    <?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {

  //send email
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail("example@live.co.uk", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  {
      echo"<form method='post' action='../index.php#contact'>

  <input type='text' name='name' class='cform' placeholder='Name...'> 

<input type='email' name='email'  class='cform' placeholder='Email...'>
<input type='text' name='subject' class='cform' placeholder='Subject...'>
<textarea name='message' id='message' class='txtarea'></textarea>
 <input  class='buttonform'type='submit'>
        </form>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: where have you defined $row_DetailRS1['email'] ?

Comment: You must locate the user's email and assign it to a variable when calling the form

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just replace the `"example@live.co.uk"` with your variable?

```
mail($row_DetailRS1['email'], $subject, $message, "From:" . $email);
```

Comment: My answer assumes you have email address saved in variable `$row_DetailRS1['email']` and that the rest of the code is working. After you do this with some user, can you check what the output of PHP is? I am sorry for poor comment on my side but I will need a little more than "not working"

Comment: I do have a variable called `$row_DetailRS1['email']` the problem is getting the email from the variable to the mail form. I tried your suggestion but nothing got sent.